# About Update Columns Null to Not Null in Code First

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, ssms

I have a database in which I have some tables in which certain columns are Null. I've made many API's in which I got that columns response are null this is hectic for mobile developers.

I want to alter those database columns to Not Null from SQL Management Studio. I am using my project code first method. Is any problem to direct update from database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to make changes in Fluent Api of Entity Framework's Code First. Open your DatabaseContext file in which you will find "OnModelCreating" Method or search with "OnModelCreating" Method in your solutions.

Now find out the column of your table in "OnModelCreating" Method and update **"WithOptional" to "WithRequired"** as you update column from Null to Not Null.